# C# WinForm - Crystal Report Does Not Show The Right Result From Inner Join Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

I'm trying to execute my inner join query in Crystal Report Viewer. The query works when run from the "New Query" section in SQL Server.

```
SELECT TABLE1.column1,TABLE2.column1
FROM TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE2.Identifier=TABLE1.Identifier
WHERE DateFrom='1/1/2016' AND DateTo='1/1/2017'
```

But when I put my code into the report, the results are incorrect by comparison. Why do the results differ when this SQL is run from the report?

```
DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();

cystalreportName crn = new cystalreportName();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = dbcon.getcon();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "..."; // the inner join query the I used.

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "TABLE2");
    crn.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["TABLE2"]);

    crystalreportviewer.ReportSource = crn;
    crystalreportviewer.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Have you look at the content of ds.Tables["TABLE2"]?

Comment: I included that table in my crystal report data source. But I wonder why in my crystal report viewer, it executes all the data inside of it. The execute would be something like in my inner query definition.

Comment: Have you look at the content of ds.Tables["TABLE2"] before you assign it to your Crystal Report?

Comment: @KiNeTiC you mean, I should put some break points in it?

Comment: Using breakpoint and checking your variables content is a nice way to debug an application.

Comment: But you know you can take a look at your DataSet content while in break point, right?

Comment: Yes, but I am going to send you the screenshots. It's weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117266/discussion-between-kinetic-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest run your query first at your  working  Database then paste it into your project or paste in in command(Crystal Report wizard). It will solved your problem.

Like this sample Query:

```
    select a.user_id,a.user_name,b.desctiption from
    (select user_id,user_name from user) as a
    left join
    (select user_id,description from item) as b
    on a.user_id = b.user_id



    or you can make it stored procedure:
    create procedure proc_sample()
    begin
       select a.user_id,a.user_name,b.description from
       (select user_id,user_name from user) as a
       left join
       (select user_id,description from item) as b
       on a.user_id = b.user_id;
    end


    Calling procedure:

    call proc_sample() at your project or in crystal report command
```

Comment: How can I call the proc_sample() in my crystal report?

Comment: are you using odbc connection for your crystal report?